# I want to install a plug-in called kuromoji in ElascticSearch and run it on CireclCI

Tags: elasticsearch, circleci

I am trying to run an app that runs on Rails and ElasticSearch with CireclCI.
And I was able to start Rails and ElascticSearch by specifying multiple images in config.yml of CireclCI.
However, when the plug-in called kuromoji was installed in ElascticSearch, the process was not completed and the port was not listening.

I will write the details below.

config.yml

```
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.6.4-browsers
      - image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.1
        command: bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-kuromoji
        environment:
          http.host: '0.0.0.0'
          http.port: 9200
          xpack.security.enabled: false
    steps:
      ....
```

On the CireclCI management screen, it was displayed as follows.

```
Container docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.1 46m5s

-> Downloading analysis-kuromoji from elastic
[=================================================] 100%?? 
-> Installed analysis-kuromoji
```

Thank you for reading so far.
I will wait for your reply

Comment: Could you share more output from elasticsearch, what is happening after the plugin was installed?

Comment: Rob Thank you comment. Output did not come out except this. I can connect to "circleci / ruby: 2.6.4-browsers" with ssh, but I don't know how to connect with "elasticsearch: 5.6.1" with SSH. This makes it more difficult to identify the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a custom image with kuromoji.